# In React, how to assign data to state Object and capture state change in dataModel

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have react component in which I have two tables bring data independently via API. The records in table B depends upon row clicked in Table A. so I need to capture the table A click event along with data.

I have define const and setting its values with each click in table A. I am print out this value but I have realise the selectedScheduleId is one record behind. so lets say if in table A, previous value of scheduleId =10 and current is 12. Console.log( selectedScheduleId) will print 10. which is not correct. I want to change selectedScheduleId value as it coming from Table A.

Also How can I know that selectedScheduleId value is change so that I can refresh Table B?

```
const [selectedScheduleId, setSelectedScheduleId] = useState(0);

 const selectedScheduleRow = (row: any) => { 
    
  console.log("schedule clicked", row.row.original.eziScheduleId);

  if(row.row.original.eziScheduleId!=null && row.row.original.eziScheduleId!=0){
    setSelectedScheduleId(row.row.original.eziScheduleId);
    console.log("setSelectedScheduleId val  ",selectedScheduleId);
  }
```

[image]

### component table

```
 return (
    <div>
    <h3>Table A</h3>
    <TableItemsTabs          
        apiUrl={api.EziTrackerSchedule}
    ></TableItemsTabs>

    <h3>Table B</h3>
    <TableItemsTabs          
        apiUrl={api.EziTrackerTransactionCollection}  // calling the API directly...
        columns={transactionColumns}
        customParams = {selectedScheduleId}  // this is where I am setting the ID
    ></TableItemsTabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here just after assigning value to SelectedScheduleId you are doing a console.log which wont show you the updated value,what you really need to do is move your console.log from there inside a useEffect like below:

```
useEffect(()=>{
console.log(selectedSchedulId);
},[selectedScheduleId]);
```

this way you can test if selectedScheduleId has got changed or not.

Comment: so If my table is in return (<div>... that is calling the API, how I will refresh it?

Comment: I have update question with table code.. The issue is this table calling the API directly so how I am going to refresh it?

Comment: instead of calling the api there directly why dont you call the api just after this assignment:`setSelectedScheduleId(row.row.original.eziScheduleId);`?

Comment: and whatever data this api call sends store it somehwere and render this data using a table.